# How to find coordinates for a point on a shape in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates, flash-cs5, shapes, point

How do you find the coordinates for (lightX, lightX) on this shape? The shape moves and rotates with a character each frame. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
my_shape2.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x990000, .75);
my_shape2.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1); 
my_shape2.graphics.moveTo(26, 26);
my_shape2.graphics.lineTo(lightX, lightX);
my_shape2.graphics.endFill();
my_shape2.x = gamelevel.Flashlightarm.x+gamelevel.x;
my_shape2.y = gamelevel.Flashlightarm.y;
my_shape2.rotation = -angle + 45;
```

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear. What are those values for? What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. (telepath mode on) I expect that you are drawing a shape that's attached to a player somewhere. If so, you'd better draw it once, then assign it `rotation` to face the correct side. Otherwise, and if you badly need to have a point on the player to connect to a point in another shape elsewhere, put this shape on stage level untransformed, and use `localToGlobal()` and `globalToLocal()` accordingly to transform coordinate spaces.

[The manual on both functions (scroll down to find the second)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal%28%29)